# Image not be picked in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, imagepicker

I am using the below code to get pick image in flutter application, when the code is run on Android it works fine, but when the same code is run on iOS it crashes the app while tapping the button to pick the image.
How should I resolve it?

ERROR I GET

> Lost connection to device.

```
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  Future getImage() async {
    print("get image");

    PickedFile image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        final File file = File(image.path);
        avatarImageFile = file;
        isLoading = true;

      });
    }
  }
```

info.plist properties[image]

Comment: what pub lib you using?

Comment: @Haryanvi I am using https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#-readme-tab-

Comment: @JohnnyWarner Please try my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to add the below permission in** `Info.plist` **file in XCode.**

**Camera :**

```
Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description   
Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use
```

**Photo :**

```
Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description    
Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use
```

Comment: I tried it , but it is till giving the same error, added the info.plist in the question above

Comment: @JohnnyWarner Please share what's the error you got?

Comment: @JohnnyWarner Please try to run in the real device after clean the project

Comment: Resolved it in simulator only by rebuilding the project

Comment: Which simulator version are you using? I am getting the same issue after doing this answer. My simulator version is 14.2. @NikunjKumbhani